# Visual studio C# Oracle database sort Date

Tags: c#, oracle, date

I am not able to find what's wrong with the following code. There is a form on which the selected start date and finish date , as well as a button transition to a new form where DataGridView populated the database , it is necessary to conclusions regarding the selected date , but that he does not want to issue ORA- 00933.No "where" all is well.

```
void renewOtchet()
        {
            dgvOtchet.Rows.Clear();
            OracleCommand ocm = Oracle.DBConneciton.CreateCommand();
            ocm.CommandText = "select num, date_start, date_finish, " +
                "trim(name_video), price_video, " +
                "trim(fam_client), " +
                "trim(kind_zal) from video.allData" +
                "where date_start >=  ('"+ date1 + "', 'DD.MM.YYYY' )  and date_finish <= ('" + date2+ "', 'DD.MM.YYYY') ";
            string[] str = new string[7];
            OracleDataReader ord = ocm.ExecuteReader();
            while (ord.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    str[i] = ord[i].ToString();
                    if (i == 1 || i == 2)
                    {
                        str[i] = str[i].Remove(10);
                    }
                }
                dgvOtchet.Rows.Add(str);
            }
            ord.Dispose();
            ord.Close();
        }
```

Comment: May be you need a space between `allData` and `where`?

Comment: I do not quite understand. About how much space you have in mind?

Comment: the where clause is missing a method - should read `"where date_start >=  TO_DATE('"+ date1 + "', 'DD.MM.YYYY' )  and date_finish <= TO_DATE('" + date2+ "', 'DD.MM.YYYY') ";`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
"select num, date_start, date_finish, " +
     "trim(name_video), price_video, " + "trim(fam_client), " +
     "trim(kind_zal) from video.allData " +
     "where date_start >=  TO_DATE('"+ date1 + "', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ) 
      and date_finish <= TO_DATE('" + date2+ "','DD.MM.YYYY') ";
      string[] str = new string[7];
```

Comment: Now gives ORA-01830 :(

Comment: How are you formatting `date1` and `date2`?  I always opt for YYYY-MM-DD formatting with oracle